# App Build is not appearing on App Store Connect submission Dashboard

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store

I have a Flutter developed App that I want to upload for App Store Review.

The App has been successfully uploaded through Xcode as you can see here— https://prntscr.com/26m7w94

Sadly, the Build doesn’t appear in my App Connect Build section as you can see here— https://prnt.sc/26no755

When I try to re-upload, it let’s me know that the Build is already uploaded to App Store Connect as you can see here— https://prnt.sc/26no84v
 
I have written to Apple and I don’t understand the answers they are giving me. They are just talking off-point.

Now I have waited for 8 days for this build to appear, but this uploaded build is not appearing.

Without this Build appearing, I cannot Submit to App Store Review.

Everything in the App Store Connect Form has been completely filled. Only Build remains to be added as you can see here— https://prntscr.com/26no94s

I can’t figure out what to do next, and this is 8(eight) wasted days gone by, with me not knowing what next to do.

Has anyone here faced this kind of problem before? How did you solve it?

Regards

Comment: Go to the TestFlight section. The build should be visible there. If it is stuck in some status - report to Apple support.

Comment: I have done as prescribed by @Charles Rostaing. I have filled the information in the TestFlight section. The build still does not show as seen here-- https://prnt.sc/26no84v 

I have spent the whole of last week talking to Apple Support, but Apple Support is the worst I’ve seen so far. They talk off-point and don’t even say anything related to the problem I’m complaining about to them.

Please any other thing I can try?

Comment: Do you see the build in the TestFlight section?  What does the build meta data show?  If the build does not appear in the app review area it is typically because 1) the version # in the build does not match the version number you have in App Store connect or the version number in the build is lower than the version number you have previously submitted in App Store connect.  I would change the version number in your build and AppStore connect to 1.0.1 or something and upload a new build. It should appear within 10 minutes.

Comment: I have changed version number to 1.0.1 and it's now giving this error--https://prntscr.com/26pgg67       Is there a possibility that I can do Chrome Remote Desktop and you can help me take a look at it?

Comment: I have corrected issues with incrementing Build Number. Then it succeeded to upload as seen here—https://prntscr.com/26phsov

Yet, the Build still does not appear in my Build section of App Store Connect, nor does it appear in TestFlight.

At this point I am so confused and frustrated. Shouldn’t it be so straight forward?

Please I need help seriously. 

Can we Schedule a Chrome Remote Access? So that you can come into my system and try to help me check?

Regards
.

Answer (score 29):

If the build doesn't show up on App Store Connect. You may want to check your email (the one you used as your Apple Id when uploading the build).

In my case Apple sent me an automatic email telling me that my build had some issues. Xcode didn't complain about anything nor App Store Connect.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I am fixing the issues now. It looks like I chose some packages which I dont use, and Apple is asking for clarification why I need those.

Comment: Thanks, I checked my email and found some deprecations occur.

Answer (score 17):

Check in the TestFlight section. There might be a yellow triangle next to your build.  You may need to answer some additional questions such as encryption usage etc. Just click on the triangle to answer and your build should be available afterwards.

Comment: I have done as you prescribed. I have filled the information in the TestFlight section. The build still does not show as seen here-- https://prnt.sc/26no84v 

Is there some other things I can try?

I have spent the whole of last week talking to Apple Support, but Apple Support is the worst I’ve seen so far. They talk off-point and don’t even say anything related to the problem I’m complaining about to them.

Please any other thing I can try?

Comment: Have you tried incrementing the build or the version number ? Did you submit a version previously ? Only build versions higher than the highest already submitted will appear in the list of available apps to publish.

Comment: For example if you have submitted a 1.0.0 (1) to the store, you can only see 1.0.1 and over. If you havent submitted 1.0.0 (1) but already uploaded it to ap connect, you can upload new builds of the same version for example 1.0.0 (2)

Comment: I have changed version number to 1.0.1 and it's now giving this error--https://prntscr.com/26pgg67       Is there a possibility that I can do Chrome Remote Desktop and you can help me take a look at it?

Comment: I have corrected issues with incrementing Build Number. Then it succeeded to upload as seen here—https://prntscr.com/26phsov

Yet, the Build still does not appear in my Build section of App Store Connect, nor does it appear in TestFlight.

At this point I am so confused and frustrated. Shouldn’t it be so straight forward?

Please I need help seriously. 

Can we Schedule a Chrome Remote Access? So that you can come into my system and try to help me check?

Regards
.

Comment: For the second warning: You need to make sure that you always increment the version and build number of your other packages (such as OneSignalNotification one) to match the one of your app.

Comment: As you see in the screenshot, you have an error in the build. You should be receiving an email too when uploading after a few minutes with the details of the error.
Here you need to go to your Info.plist file and add the missing key/values based on what your app requires.

Comment: After you upload a build, it usually takes about 5min to appear in the TestFlight list but in 'Processing' status. About another 15min later, it should be ready with the yellow triangle if you haven't yet done the setup to avoid that each time.

Comment: I have corrected issues with incrementing Build Number. Then it succeeded to upload as seen here—https://prntscr.com/26phsov

Yet, the Build still does not appear in my Build section of App Store Connect, nor does it appear in TestFlight. See it here— https://prntscr.com/26plpnx

Can we Schedule a Chrome Remote Access? So that you can come into my system and try to help me check?

Regards
.

Comment: Ok we can try that

Comment: Can you check that the appid match and that you are looking at the right app/account etc ?

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes the answer to this issue is that there is actually a problem with App Store Connect (like right now).

You can check for issues on the [Apple Developer System Status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) page.

Comment: doesn't help when their callback service and their email contact form aren't working either.

Comment: @Sean not entirely, since at that point you know that contacting them wouldn't help, since you know you're not doing anything wrong and that there's an issue they're already working on.

Answer (score 3):

For me changing the version from **X.X.X** to **X.X.X+1** (2.2.2 -> 2.2.3) fixed the issue.

Comment: This is resolved

Comment: Nice answer, why Apple does not provide any error message in this case? anyway, thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was because the iOS build was missing some permission strings. The only indication was the email you get from App Store Connect pre-screening. It shows which permission string is missing exactly. After adding that and resubmitting, the builds started showing up.

Comment: thank you helped me!  i forgot to add contacts string in info.plist

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens and I have also faced this problem .I successfully uploaded my bundle from Xcode but not found in connect.
I waited 30 minutes and refreshed .Then my bundle came in App Store connect.

Solution 1 : wait for some time & Refresh ,
Solution 2 : Create another Bundle and push to connect using Transporter (You can download transporter from appStore)

Comment: Same issue for me. I found out I missed the email Apple sent me. It went to a folder instead of inbox. Try to search title like this in your email:  App Store Connect: Your app "appname" (Apple ID: 12345 Version: 1.0.1 Build: 0) has one or more issues.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for a minimum of 30 minutes, and it will come; stay relaxed.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This might have boiled down to timing. After changing the version number to 1.0.0, that build showed up immediately. Half an hour later, the 0.0.1 build appeared out of the blue as well.

---

If you've set your version number to 0.0.1+X because you thought that makes sense while the app is still under development, change that back to 1.0.0+X. The upload will succeed, but app store connect won't list the build without a leading "1." in the version number.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing the type account on the app store connect from development to app manager

Answer (score -1):

it will come after 10 minutes. I have facing this issue 4-5 times;

Answer (score -3):

Make sure no webviews (UIWebView that is) are used in your app. It will not show builds in App Store Connect and neither XCode nor Apple will say that anything is wrong.

Comment: webviews are perfectly legal, just need to follow best security practices.

Comment: @Mishka: What do yo mean legal? You are not going to go to jail for using them. However, newly submitted or updated apps will be rejected by AppStore, if you have UIWebView in it. You must switch to WKWebView. In my case they did not alert me but just blocked my builds.

Comment: Yes of course you should not be using outdated deprecated API's especially for webviews